# Udefined variable $product error on update form submition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Please am trying to update my product entry in the database but I get an undefined variable error on submit. The form is supposed to update my database entry but when I route to the update method without passing the product id, I get a missing parameter product error and when add itas is the code below, I get an undefined variable product error

This is my update function

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $my_array = [$request->file('primary_image'), $request->file('image_1'), $request->file('image_2')];
    $insert_array = [];

    foreach ($my_array as $item) {
        $save_url = '';
        if ($item) {
            $image = $item;
            $name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)) .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($image)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
            $save_url = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;
        }

        array_push($insert_array, $save_url);
    }

    $product = Product::find($product->id);
    $product->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'status' => $request -> status,
        'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
        'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity,
        'colors' => $request->colors,
        'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
        'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone,
        'video_description' => $request->video_description,
        'primary_image' => $insert_array[0],
        'image_1' => $insert_array[1],
        'image_2' => $insert_array[2],
    ]);


    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Product created successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
}
```

this is my blade component

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update', ['products' => $product->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    @csrf

    <h4 class="card-title">Edit Product</h4><br><br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mbr-1">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                        id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input"
                    class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="category" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                        id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="price" class="form-control" type="number"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="status" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                        id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product
            Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea id="elm1" name="description" placeholder="Please enter a vivid description of the product"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tags</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="tags" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                        id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estimated
                    Delivery
                    Time</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="estimated_delivery_time" class="form-control" type="text"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Available
                    Quantity</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="available_quantity" class="form-control" type="text"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Colors</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="colors" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                        id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier's
                    Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="supplier_name" class="form-control" type="text"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier's
                    Contact</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="supplier_contact" class="form-control" type="text"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Video Url /
                    Link</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="video_description" class="form-control" type="text"
                        value="" id="example-text-input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Primarry
                    Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="primary_image" accept="image/*" class="form-control"
                        type="file" id="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Primary Image
                    Preview</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img id="showImage" class="" width="300px" src="{{ (!empty($product->image))? url($product->image):url('upload/no_image.jpg') }}" alt="Product image">
                    {{-- <img id="showImage" class="" width="300px"src="{{ !empty($product->image) ? url($product->image):url('upload/no_image.jpg') }}"alt="Hero image"> --}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Add Second Image
                    </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="image_1" accept="image/*" class="form-control"
                        type="file" id="image" multiple="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Add Third Image
                    </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="image_2" accept="image/*" class="form-control"
                        type="file" id="image" multiple="">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" value="Edit Product">
</form>
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for taking the time to review my code

Comment: In the form you're passing id to the ``products`` parameter but in the controller you're accessing ``$product->id`` Change to ``$products->id``

Comment: Did you know straight SQL is simple compared to the complexity Lavarel adds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some refinements to add:

1. You have product from route model binding at first no need to find it again here: `$product = Product::find($product->id);`
2. You are passing the products but your route needs product.
3. Instead of `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` use `@method('PUT')` in your form.
4. If you had validation you had the data after validation and this code

   `$product->update([ 'name' => $request->name, 'category' => $request->category, 'price' => $request->price, 'description' => $request->description, 'status' => $request -> status, 'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time, 'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity, 'colors' => $request->colors, 'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name, 'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone, 'video_description' => $request->video_description, 'primary_image' => $insert_array[0], 'image_1' => $insert_array[1], 'image_2' => $insert_array[2], ]);`

   would be transferred to

   `$validatedData = $request->validate([ .... ]); $product->update($validatedData + [ 'primary_image' => $insert_array[0], 'image_1' => $insert_array[1], 'image_2' => $insert_array[2], ]);`

   or even moving the validation to a separate form request class.